# compile pjsip library in mingw- windows platform

Tags: pjsip

Can anybody please explain me the step by step procedure to compile and build pjsip libraries in MINGW platform?
I dont want to build the same using visual studio solution file.!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this step by step instructions: 
http://blog.chinaunix.net/uid-23405046-id-4727233.html

I tried to compile pjsua2 dll within Visual Studio but with no luck, I only success to compile static .lib but not .dll. So I used above tutorial with mingw and success compile pjsip and also pjsua2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did to build pjsip in Mingw64.
Edit your prefix and make options.
Be sure that gcc or clang are in your $PATH.

```
!/bin/bash
cd ./pjproject-2.6

PREFIX=./OUT
MAKEOPTS='-j4'

./configure --prefix=${PREFIX} --enable-shared --enable-video
make ${MAKEOPTS} dep
make ${MAKEOPTS}
make ${MAKEOPTS} install
```

After this script execution you will get libraries in $PREFIX/lib path. But it could not create pakcage config file so make install command fill exit with error status.

PS.
Patches that i've made while was trying to build pjsip.

```
https://gist.github.com/dobokirisame/7b1d1ef3b761b7c77e07467a91b7db5c
https://gist.github.com/dobokirisame/d4e699335354ee66596d0573ed297f21
https://gist.github.com/dobokirisame/d3f481a4add2e59d98a73964ef3e582a
```